# Want to know more about warning: comparison between pointer and integer in C programming

Tags: c, pointers, null

Below there is a small program which I came across and thought to search more on it. It gives a `warning: comparison between pointer and integer`

```
 if ( NULL == '\1' )
```

I'm just unable to figure out that which one is pointer and which one is integer and more important why so?

I can just say that NULL is pointer here but don't know why so?

Yes, one more thing is there when we replace the `NULL` with `'\0'` then there is no compilation warning. Why?

The full code is :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    if ( NULL == '\1' )
    {
       printf (" \nTrue "); 
    }
    else
    {
        printf (" \nFalse");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Comparison between pointer and integer in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223095/comparison-between-pointer-and-integer-in-c)

Comment: In C, NULL is typically defined as: #define NULL ((void *)0), which is different than it's C++ definition.    So, in C, NULL is a pointer.

Comment: thank's , in c++ NULL isn't a pointer or it is?

Comment: In C++, depending on the version of C++, it is either 0L or nullptr.

Comment: Tags need to be fixed, the answer is different depending on the language.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can only compare things that are comparable in nature. Integers and addresses are too different to be comparable; integers are values, while addresses are pointers to values, their usages are too different to consider them comparable.

`NULL` is defined as `((void *)0)` which is a special constant for pointers that denotes a pointer that never points to something... It is typed as a pointer. `void *` is the universal type for pointers.

`\1` is a constant for `char` (it is the character of index 1 in the ASCII table, it is known as SOH char). A char is roughly a number that *can* be easily translated to a char when printed. You literal is 1 typed as a char, but for efficiency, in almost all arithmetic and comparison expressions, every such char is converted to an `int`.

So you basically compare a pointer to an int as the compiler says. This is not strictly forbidden, but the compiler as usual has a serious doubt about this and warns you. Effectively, you expression has no sense.

If you really want to compare both (again probably non sense), then you can either:

1. convert the pointer to an int (this is dangerous as you surely lose information in that conversion) : `((int)NULL) == '\1',
2. convert the literal value to a pointer (less dangerous but also stupid) : `NULL == (void *)'\1'

Comment: This question was just for gaining more information about the NULL and '\0' not for creating any stupidity

Comment: I know. Sorry if *stupid* is the wrong word, I'm not English native, I may make some misuse; forgive me if it is so.

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` is a null pointer constant. It's typically defined as:

```
#define NULL 0
```

or

```
#define NULL ((void *)0)
```

Based on the warning message you get, it looks like your implementation has the latter definition.

Hence, the comparison produces the warning message as you are comparing a pointer and an `int`. Character literals are of type `int` in C.

> Yes, one more thing is there when we replace the NULL with '\0' then
>   there is no compilation warning. Why?

That's because comparing an `int` (`'\0'`) with another `int` (`'\1'`) is fine.

Comment: Wrong. In C++ (tag on the question) NULL CAN NOT be defined as `(void*)0`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice C++ tag (I follow C tag). Besides, the code looks like C code and title says C. Perhaps, the C++ tag needs to go.

Comment: Agree, one of those is misplaced, but I do not know which one :)

Answer (score 1):

`NULL`, `0` and `'\0'` have a slightly different meanings. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0) for more information. `NULL` is designt to be the null pointer while `0` is a constant literal of the integer *0*. You can use constant literals of the the integer *0* for pointers too. Thay have some special meaning in such situations. This mean you can use `0` in all such situations but `NULL` should only be used for pointers. If you would have an integer which is not 0, it would not make much sense to compare it with a pointer. Remember, while using *C/C++*, you don't know how pointers are represented at the hardware.

In C `NULL` is often implemented as `((void*)0)`. In C++ it may be implemented as `0`.

---

If you write `NULL == 0` in *C*, you are comparing an integer with a pointer. Since `0` is a constant literal for the integer *0*, it has a special meaning and doesn't generate any warning or error. But if you have another integer there, maybe `1`, it does not make much sense to compare it with `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

It only really makes sense to compare `NULL` to memory addresses.  `1` is clearly not a meaningful memory address but `0` is a commonly referenced memory address.  If you are comparing `NULL` to any non-pointer value other than `0`, it is highly suggestive of a logic error, and that's why you get a warning.

Perhaps you were thinking of the unofficial-but-common macro `NUL` which is defined as `'\0'`.